# Custom Alert Dialogs undefined method

Tags: android, dialog, android-alertdialog

i am new to android and i am trying to get this custom dialog to work, i get an error on `showDialog` & `removeDialog` which says The method `removeDialog(int)` is undefined for the type `new DialogInterface.OnClickListener`.

`onReceive` method:

```
showDialog(DIALOG_TEXT_ENTRY);
```

Code:

```
    private static final int MY_PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID = 0;

    MediaPlayer mp;
    Context context;   

    protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id, Context context) {

        Dialog dialog = null;
        switch(id) {
        case MY_PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID:
            LayoutInflater factory = LayoutInflater.from(context);

            final View textEntryView = factory.inflate(R.layout.password_dialog, null);

            final EditText password1 = (EditText) textEntryView.findViewById(R.id.inputPassword);

            AlertDialog.Builder builder = new AlertDialog.Builder(context);
            builder.setTitle("Enter Password");
            builder.setView(textEntryView);

            builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                      removeDialog(MY_PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID);
                   }
                });

                AlertDialog passwordDialog = builder.create();
                return passwordDialog; 
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: Do something like this: `Dialog dialog = onCreateDialog(); dialog.show()`. That should display your dialog. and to dismiss and everyone said call `dialog.dismiss()`

Answer (score 2):

use

```
dialog.dismiss();
```

instead of

```
removeDialog(MY_PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID);
```

you cant show a dialog in a BroadcastReceiver.

but still, if you want to show a popup screen, then create an activity, with Dialog theme.

Comment: what's about showDialog? I'm unable to show my dialog in the first place

Comment: I'm trying to use it in a BroadcastReceiver in the onReceive method, had a typo in the post. The method showDialog() is undefined for the type FinderReceiver

Comment: In a broadcast receiver you cant show a dialog, instead you should use Notificationss or Toasts to notify some event, and if you still want to show alert, you can do this by starting an activity with theme dialog.

Comment: is broadcast receiver  in any activity.

Comment: public class FinderReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {

Comment: jeet is right you can use an activity with dilog theme and when calling the activity add i.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); also otherwise it can give a crash

Answer (score 1):

You can also use

```
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
                       dialog.cancel(); 
                   }
                });
```

on button click it should work fine

can refer this link also

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html#AddingButtons

Answer (score 0):

you should use `dialog.dismiss();` instead of your removeDialog() method.

Answer (score 0):

See below. Use **dismiss();**

```
builder.setPositiveButton(android.R.string.cancel, new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
   public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int whichButton) {
      dismiss();
   }
};
```

Call this way `showDialog(MY_PASSWORD_DIALOG_ID);`

Refer this [Create Custom Dialog tutorial](http://android-coding.blogspot.in/2011/05/create-custom-dialog-with-dynamic.html)

```
@Override
protected Dialog onCreateDialog(int id) {
 // TODO Auto-generated method stub

 screenDialog = null;
 switch(id){
 case(ID_SCREENDIALOG):
  screenDialog = new Dialog(this);
  screenDialog.setContentView(R.layout.screendialog);
  bmImage = (ImageView)screenDialog.findViewById(R.id.image);
  TextOut = (TextView)screenDialog.findViewById(R.id.textout);
  btnScreenDialog_OK = (Button)screenDialog.findViewById(R.id.okdialogbutton);
  btnScreenDialog_OK.setOnClickListener(btnScreenDialog_OKOnClickListener);
 }
 return screenDialog;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

use dialog.dismiss();

plz refer to following link 
http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html